Repacing/normalizing Arabic letters with Javascript
I have a search which return some products from API, these products in Arabic
the Arabic language has many letters looks like the same, for example ( أ - ا ), (ي - ى ), ( ه - ة). I need when I write ه it will search for ( ه and ة) and return the products which contain the ه or ة in table
Example: there's 5 products containing (ه), and 5 products containing (ة) so I need when I type any letter of them it returns 10 products. How to do this?
I tried this:
const normalizeSearchPhrase = (phrase) => {
    return phrase 
    .replace(/أ|ا/g, "ا") 
    .replace(/ي|ى/g, "ي") 
    .replace(/ة|ه/g, "ه"); 
  };

I expected it to return any product containing أ or ا when I type any of them to get the 10 product but it replace a letter with the other one so it return 5 products not the 10 as example above.

I removed the react tag (this has nothing to do specifically with react) and added some other hopefully useful tags.

Don't, and make your database do that work for you based on the fact that it knows how to perform the various normalizations and string comparisons. But if you absolutely have to do this client-side, read through the String normalization options available in JS. Having said that, the idea that ي and ى are the same for search purposes is... questionable at best.
